# Bootstrap collapse without unique identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the bootstrap collapse plugin in such a way that a unique identifier is not required. Normally there is usually a single or a couple of collapsible elements on a page.

But my elements are generated dynamically and passing index keys is overkill.

What happens now is that if I toggle the collapse for `element2`, it will collapse `element1`. Obviously because they have the same ID.

Any way to achieve this without actually giving each collapsible element a unique id?

Here's a functional js fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hhvrjnr3/

Comment: "passing index keys is overkill." This doesn't make much sense. Just generate both the link and the div with the same dynamically generated id.

Comment: @devJunk is correct. How is it overkill? That and I don't see any other way

Comment: Well I wanted to try to get it to work without having to do that. Obviously That is a possibility and I had it working that way but the way the code is written now it will turn into a bit off a mess.

EDIT: Using the ID is, in my opinion, an easy way out. Apparently it can't be done using the plugin itself. But it **can** be done by using jquery's `find()` and `parent()` methods. So i'll just do that then.

Comment: Here you go - http://jsfiddle.net/hhvrjnr3/1/ No need for id's :-)

Comment: No need for the passive aggressiveness. I was just referring to the fact that passing the ids is in no way overkill.

Comment: In my case it was. If I could I would, but the current setup just prevents it. That's the sole reason I asked this question. Thanks for the help though

Comment: It's a joke that you can't create an accordion with Bootstrap out the box without passing a unique identifier.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It can be done. First remove the `data-target="#collapseExample"` from the elements you want to collapse. Then add an extra class to your toggle button, I've added 'collapser'. That's not really needed, but it's nice to identify the toggle button. Then add some jQuery to do the toggling, in this case I am using `next()` to get the subsequent element to the toggle button which is your element you wish to collapse.

```
$('.collapser').click(function() {
    $(this).next().collapse('toggle');
});
```

[Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hhvrjnr3/3/)