# how to open bootstrap modal-dialog without id or class using JQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

For some reasons i cannot set *id* or *class* for my **Bootstrap modal-dialog** and i need a way to make them work without it, by maybe using **JQuery** or **JavaScript**?

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
<div class="container">
 
      <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg"  >Open Modal 1</button>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade"  role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
    
          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text11 in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
      </div>
    
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg"  >Open Modal 2</button>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade"  role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
    
          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text22 in the modal.</p>
            </div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
      
        </div>
      </div>
  
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Sankar for the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*define onclick function to both buttons and pass this as parameter and then use next() property of jquery*

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" onclick="firstmodal(this)" >Open Modal 1</button>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade"  role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text11 in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
      </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

**js**

```
function firstmodal(ele){
$(ele).next().modal('show');
}
```

**Do the same for other modal as well**

Comment: no, i cannot put different Onclick functions , cannot put id's either  i need a solution like this [Collapsibe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369836/bootstrap-collapse-without-unique-identifier)

like what they did with collapsible @akshay

Comment: my friend you do not have to add different function the same function can be used for both modal  **this** will state which button is clicked

Comment: oops sorry ... Thank you so much :) it worked @akshay

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var buttons = $(".container button");

    if(buttons.length > 0){
        buttons[0].on("click", function(){
            //this will return two modals
            var modals = $(".container div.modal")

            if(modals.length > 0){
                modals[0].modal("toggle");
            }
        })
    }

    if(buttons.length > 1){
        buttons[1].on("click", function(){
            //this will return two modals
            var modals = $(".container div.modal")

            if(modals.length > 1){
                modals[1].modal("toggle");
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Hope that solves the problem

Comment: no i cannot put id's either  i need a solution like this [Collapsibe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369836/bootstrap-collapse-without-unique-identifier)

like what they did with collapsible

Comment: I have edited my answer. How about now ? You don't need to specify the ids on buttons either

Comment: Welcome :) Are u using this solution or the accepted answer ?

Comment: Accepted answer.. Fewer lines of code :P  Thanks by the way :)